# PHP: Serialized array is saved in (by humans) unreadable UTF-16LE encoded .txt file -- bug or intended behaviour?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, character-encoding

I am teaching myself programming websites with OOP in PHP (using XAMPP Version 7.3.14 for Windows), and recently I learned how to save serialized arrays containing objects (`file_put_contents('path/filename.txt', serialize($array));`). I did this already with normal arrays. In order to practice a bit, I wrote a little website with a form template for adding new records and a display template for printing out a list with links to individual records on screen as I encountered the following phenomenon:

In the class definition of the objects (instantiated as elements of a one-dimensional numeric array) I am working with all properties are initialized as `protected` and their values are got and set with getter and setter methods in the actual program code outside the class definition. When I added a new record to the array (which at that point was still read from PHP code) and saved the array for the first time the resulting .txt file is encoded in UTF-8 and the serialized string shows the "normal" syntax in latin letters such as:

```
a:4:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":6:{s:13:" * property_1"; s:7:"value_1"; ...
```

However, after I had modified the program code in a way that the data now are read from the very .txt file (`unserialize(file_get_contents('path/filename.txt', $array));`) and I saved it again, the resulting file is encoded in UTF-16LE and contains Chinese characters so that it is unreadable to me! Nevertheless that file is obviously still readable by the PHP interpreter. Further testing revealed that this behaviour seems to be related to the protection status of the properties. After changing the initialization mode of the properties to `public`, the UTF-16LE encoded file is read but when saved again it turns back into a "normal" UTF-8 encoded file.

Finally my question: Is that known behaviour or is it a bug of my PHP interpreter? When I searched the internet I did not find anything that would fit to my observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP serialization is not a humanreadable format. Also there you can see in manual:

```
Note that this is a binary string which may include null bytes
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Private and protected properties brings null bytes. For example

```
class A{
    private $b='0';
}

echo bin2hex(serialize(new A())), PHP_EOL;
echo serialize(new A());
```

Output

```
4f3a313a2241223a313a7b733a343a2200410062223b733a313a2230223b7d
 O : 1 : " A " : 1 : { s : 4 : "   A   b " ; s : 1 : " 0 " ; }
                                 ^   ^
                                 |   | null bytes
                                   ^
                                   |  class name for private or * for protected
```

Null byte string is not printable, so, you text editor "decided" that you need other encoding.

Comment: OK, sorry for wrong use of the term "human-readable". What I meant is that I know the meaning of the characters in the serialized string when encoded in UTF-8.

And thanks for the hint with the editor. I used a different editor for opening the .txt file, and it opened the file in UTF-8 with "strange" characters (a black diamond with a question mark) only where the null bytes are. So it seems that you have found the solution...